# RANGE clause for window function to get the previous sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I have the following data, which I am trying to get the profit from the previous year:

```
WITH tbl (year, country, product, profit) AS (
   VALUES
     (2000, 'Finland', 'Computer'  , 1500)
   , (2000, 'Finland', 'Phone'     ,  100)
   , (2001, 'Finland', 'Phone'     ,   10)
   , (2000, 'India'  , 'Calculator',   75)
   , (2000, 'India'  , 'Calculator',   75)
   , (2000, 'India'  , 'Computer'  , 1200)
   )
select country, year, profit
     , lag(profit) over (partition by country order by year)
from tbl;

┌─────────┬──────┬────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ country ┆ year ┆ profit ┆ sum_profit_previous_year │
╞═════════╪══════╪════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ India   ┆ 2000 ┆     75 ┆                          │
│ India   ┆ 2000 ┆     75 ┆                       75 │
│ India   ┆ 2000 ┆   1200 ┆                       75 │
│ Finland ┆ 2000 ┆   1500 ┆                          │
│ Finland ┆ 2000 ┆    100 ┆                     1500 │
│ Finland ┆ 2001 ┆     10 ┆                      100 │
└─────────┴──────┴────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

However, this just seems to get the previous row, rather than what I want, which is to get the `LAG` of the profit value for the previous year for that country. The expected result should be:

```
┌─────────┬──────┬────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ country ┆ year ┆ profit ┆ sum_profit_previous_year |
╞═════════╪══════╪════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ India   ┆ 2000 ┆     75 ┆                          │
│ India   ┆ 2000 ┆     75 ┆                          │
│ India   ┆ 2000 ┆   1200 ┆                          │
│ Finland ┆ 2000 ┆   1500 ┆                          │
│ Finland ┆ 2000 ┆    100 ┆                          │
│ Finland ┆ 2001 ┆     10 ┆                   1600   │
└─────────┴──────┴────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

Since Finland-2001 is the only record that also has a record for that same country for the previous year. What would be the correct `RANGE` clause here to accomplish this? (Either BigQuery or Postgres is fine for testing purposes).

Comment: You need to aggregate the profit by country and year before you can use the LAG function.

Comment: @tinazmu I see, is there another way to do it with a window function (without aggregating), such as with the `SUM` function?

Comment: You are already aggregating by eliminating 'Product'?

Comment: I mean without a `GROUP BY` clause in the select statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indeed want all *un-aggregated* rows, and add the *aggregated* profit for the previous year ...

Here is a way with a plain window function and a custom window frame:

```sql
SELECT country, year, profit
     , sum(profit) OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY year
                         RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS sum_profit_previous_year
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY country DESC, year;  -- optional?
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gneHVu51)

[Details in the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)